# How can my program find and use a file in the same folder as the program?

Tags: python, tensorflow, matplotlib, directory, opencv

My python program is thinking, that the file image.jpg doesn't exist or isn't in the right directory.

I have already tried to give to show it more explicit where it is.But it just says that it doesn't exist. Here is the code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg
import cv2

# Laden des gespeicherten Modells
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('my_augmented_fashion_mnist_model/my_model.h5')

# Vorhersage für ein benutzerdefiniertes Bild machen
image_path = 'image.jpg'
image = mpimg.imread(image_path)
image = cv2.resize(image, (28, 28))
image = image / 255.0

# BGR zu RGB Konvertierung
image = np.flip(image, axis=-1)

prediction = model.predict(np.array([image]))
predicted_class = np.argmax(prediction[0])

# Konvertieren der Vorhersage in Klassennamen
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']
predicted_class_name = class_names[predicted_class]

# Ausgabe der Vorhersage
print("Das Bild zeigt ein ", predicted_class_name)
```

I get here the error:

```
 File "c:\Users\user\Desktop\path\Fashion Test KI.py", line 12, in <module>
    image = mpimg.imread(image_path)
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\image.py", line 1563, in imread
    with img_open(fname) as image:
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 3227, in open
    fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb")
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'image.jpg'
```

The picture is this:

[image: just a pullover in the jpg format]

I have made here an ai with the fashion collection, because I wanted to try out how an ai works.

I expected that I would get an answer that shows the accuracy of the ai of the picture.

I have already changed the format and the library from cv2 to matplotlib, and changed the directory a few times.

Comment: Where the file is located?

Comment: Something you said isn't correct, but we don't know what. Maybe something is not actually in the folder you thought it was in? Maybe you have a typo in the filename? You can print out things like print(\_\_file\_\_), or check os.path.isfile(filename), but the easiest thing is to just give it the full path to the file and just don't worry about it.

Comment: I'd delete all the code except the filename, and use os.path functions to figure out what's going on. Also look at the current python file's path as \_\_path\_\_ and the directories that python will look in are sys.path

Comment: I have tried  the os.path.isfile("image.jpg"), and it is saying me false after I runned it.What does that mean?

Comment: i have now tried to give it the full path, but it says that there is an syntax error with unicode :The error is: line 11
    image_path = 'C:\Users\finnw\Desktop\AI\image.jpg'
                                                      ^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape   I dont know what I can do because I dont know unicode.

Comment: Hey, you told us the file was in r"c:\Users\user\Desktop\path" but now you're saying it's in r"c:\Users\finnw\Desktop\AI"?

Comment: "C:\Users" has a unicode escape string \U because you didn't escape your backslashes like "C:\\Users". Just put an r in front of the whole string to disable backslashes entirely, image_path = r"..."

Comment: Thank you Kenny Ostrom I have tried that with the r and the path Problem ist solved now.Unfortunately I have now some problems with Tensor Flow.But Thank you that has helped me very much.